# How check the stripe domain file AWS LightSail

Tags: stripe-payments

Does anyone know the correct path in AWS LightSail to check the stripe domain file to release apple pay on the site, I tried all these paths and it didn't work, I'm using lighsail with cloudflare.

```
/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs
/opt/bitnami/wordpress
/var/www/
/var/www/html
```

*** shows this error ***
We received a 404 status code from your server when we tried to retrieve the file. See the reason for the request failure in your logs. Our servers may send HTTP headers that differ from those sent by your browser.